# Footer stays on the top of the content - Bootstrap 4 (ASP.NET Master/Child)

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am having issues with Bootstrap 4 and Internet explorer. I am using ASP.NET master/child forms. This is regarding the footer is always at the bottom of the pages. When content is short, the footer will be pushed to the bottom of the page; when content is longer, then the area is scrollable, and the footer will be at the bottom of the content. So this was implemented using flexbox in CSS and setting HTML and body tags to 100 % height. Everything is working fine in all browsers, except it doesn't work for Internet Explorer on small devices only; when I scale it down to mobile device width, the footer will stay in the middle of the page top of the content. In Chrome, Firefox, And Edge, everything works fine, and the footer is at the bottom of the page even for small devices.

HTML code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MIMO.master.cs" Inherits="MIMO_WEB_R03.MIMO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="h-100">
 
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.mod.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.mod.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">    
    <div class="container-fluid bg-success">
        <div class="container">
           
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-success navbar-dark" 
                    role="navigation">
            MENU ITEMS AND COLLAPSE BUTTON
                    </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
     <div class="jumbotron p-2 m-0"><div class="container text-center align-items-center">
    <h3 class="text-warning font-weight-bold" id="heading">SOME TITLE HERE</h3>
    </div>

        <div class="container d-flex align-items-end">
        LINKS TO PAGES HERE
        </div>
     </div>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Body" runat="server">
        <div id = "page-content">
            PAGE CONTENT DIV IS SPECIFIED AT CHILD PAGES        
        </div>

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <footer class="footer bg-success small">

        <!-- Footer Links -->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 p-4 text-left flex-column">
                    CONTENT
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 p-4 text-center">
            CONTENT

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

                    LINKS  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- END FOOTER SECTION -->
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* CSS TO KEEP FOOTER ALWAYS ON BOTTOM USIN FLEXBOX */

footer {

    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#page-content 
{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #page-content {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #page-content {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #page-content {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #page-content {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```